# Blank page after logging in

Tags: php, authentication

i'm trying to create a login/register system with PDO and sessions and a user can create his account and he ca access the Welcome page , but when logging out and trying to log back with working username and password , it sends me to a blank php page , i looked on the internet and a blank php page means syntax error which i can't find any.
Btw i tried typing any username with any password and it stills sending me to a blank php page 
here's my code :
Config.php

```
class config {

    public static function connect()
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "logintest";

        try{

            $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);


        }catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Connection échoué" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $bdd;
    }
}

?>
```

My process.php (that's where i think the probleme is comming from :

```
session_start();

    include_once("config.php");

        if(isset($_POST['register']))
        {
            $bdd = config::connect();
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(insertDetails($bdd,$username,$email,$password))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: profile.php");
    }

}


    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $bdd = config::connect();
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(checkLogin($bdd,$username,$password))
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: profile.php");
        }
    else{
        echo "Le mot de passe ou le nom d'utilisateur sont incorrect";
    }
}


    function insertDetails($bdd,$username,$email,$password)
        {
            $query = $bdd->prepare("

                INSERT INTO users (username,email,password)

                VALUES(:username,:email,:password)

                ");
            $query->bindParam(":username",$username);
            $query->bindParam(":email",$email);
            $query->bindParam(":password",$password);

    return $query->execute();
}


    function checkLogin($bdd,$username,$password)
    {
        $query = $bdd->prepare("

            SELECT * From users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password

        ");

        $query->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $query->bindParam(":password", $password);

        $query->execute();

    // Check how many rows are returned

        if ($query->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

my profile.php :

````
session_start();

include_once("config.php");

echo "Bienvenue " . $_SESSION['username'] . "  ";

echo "<a href='logout.php'>Se deconnecter</a>". "  ";

echo "<a href='update.php'>Mettre a jour le profile</a>" . "  ";

echo "<a href='delete.php'>Supprimer mon compte</a>". "  ";

?>```
and my logout.php :
```<?php

session_destroy();

header("Location: index.html");
?>
````

Or here's the project i'm working on : https://github.com/AmrouHab/LoginRegister/tree/master/neptunetest

I'll take any help 
Thanks
(Btw sorry for my bad english im french)

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of all your PHP files to display errors. This should help you debug the issue or else edit your question with the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , i found the solution 
I forgot to put an uppercase "L" in process.php

```
 if(isset($_POST['login']))
```

I've corrected it to

```
 if(isset($_POST['Login']))
```

and now it's working.
Thanks for your attention.